# Angular 8 and Material design navbar - show selected item

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I am trying figure out how to show the selected item when I click on it in the horizontal navbar. Here is my code:

```
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="topbar relative">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <div color="primary">
                <div>
                  <a href="#" mat-button  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/dashboard"> Accounts </a>
                  <a href="#" mat-button  routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/dashboard"> Create Account </a>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
```

Although I am using the same router link for both routes the link is real. When I click the selected item is not staying highlighted. Here is how it looks before and after selecting an item.

[image]

Any idea how to style it to show the active item?

Thanks

Comment: Are you applying a style to `.active`? routerLinkActive just adds a css-class.

Comment: No, I am not. Is it needed? I am using similar technique in Bootstrap 4 based project and it seems to work there. Although I am using pills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routerActiveLink directive just adds a css-class and leaves all the styling to you. In your case, there will be an `active` class that you can style.

```
// my.component.scss
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

Remember that if you're using @angular/material, you should probably style it using their themes. You can read more about that [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

```
// _my-theme.scss (only do this if you use material themes)
.active {
  background: mat-color($accent);
}
```

Comment: I added this .active {
  background: red;
}
to the css file for testing and now both items look red.

Comment: That is because both items have the same url: `/dashboard`. routerLinkActive will add `.active` to the element whenever you visit the url `/dashboard`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks